# How to assign dynamic value in Bigcommerce handlebar

Tags: handlebars.js

I trying to assign a dynamic value `title` to a new variable `carat1` with a custom helper, but it currently isn't working.

```
{{#each items}}
  {{assignVar "jsondata" '{["title": "{{title}}", "id": `{{id}}`, "param_name": "{{param_name}}"]}'}}
  {{getVar "jsondata"}}
  {{assignVar "carat1" "{{title}}" }}
  {{getVar "carat1"}}
{{/each}}
```

When I evaluate the code above, I see the literal string `"{{title}}"` printed but actual title value is `"this is my title"`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a [subexpression](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#subexpressions) here.

That is, in your `assignVar` helper, you don't want to pass the literal string `"{{title}}"` as the 2nd argument, but want the *value* of `title`.

Subexpressions are delimited by parentheses.

So instead of `"{{title}}"`, you'd just write `(title)` to evaluate the `title` variable *within* the `assignVar` helper.

```js
{{#each items}}
  {{assignVar "jsondata" '{["title": "{{title}}", "id": `{{id}}`, "param_name": "{{param_name}}"]}'}}
  {{getVar "jsondata"}}
  {{assignVar "carat1" (title) }}
  {{getVar "carat1"}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: In "jsondata" assignVar passed "(title)" not working

Comment: You would need to use another custom helper for this. For example, if you had the [concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/just-handlebars-helpers#concat) helper from the [just-handlebars-helpers](https://www.npmjs.com/just-handlebars-helpers) package, you could build your JSON string, with an abbreviated example like so: `{{assignVar "jsondata" (concat '{"title":"' title '"}')}}`. Note that things like quote escaping also might be something you'll need to consider.